# mysql and php database setup

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a database, so far so good. Though I seem to run into a problem that I can't find the answer for. I hope you guys can get me back on the horse.

The problem is for the registration part; here is the error.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/db/MySQLDAO.php on line 53
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/db/MySQLDAO.php:53 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/scripts/registerUser.php(40): MySQLDAO->registerUser('email1', 'aske', 'meyer', '3a2a3b51b4da4d6...', '8W\xAF:\xC6>\xEB\xA5\x10q\x85b\xC7\xFAn...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swiftappandmysql/db/MySQLDAO.php on line 53"

MySQL line:53

```
public function registerUser($email, $first_name, $last_name, $password, $salt)
{
    $sql = "insert into users set email=?, first_name=?, last_name=?, user_password=?, salt=?";
    $statement = $this->Conn->prepare($sql);

    if(!$statement)
        throw new Exception($statement->error);

    $statement->bind_param("sssss", $email, $first_name, $last_name, $password, $salt);
    $returnValue = $statement->execute();

    return $returnValue;
}
```

and the registerUser line 40:

```
$result =$dao->registerUser($userEmail, $userFirstName, $userLastName, $secured_password, $salt);
```

Comment: `if(!$statement) throw new Exception($statement->error);` won't work which is why you have the Line 53 notice.  If statement is false, how can you get a property of it? (`$statement->error`)

Comment: hey @Devon i tried, though it did not seem to be the problem i changed it to        . if(!$statement)
  throw new Exception($statement);

Comment: Of course that isn't the only problem.  You have to find out why statement is false, why would you throw an exception with a message of false/null/empty?  Think about what you are throwing here.

Comment: @Devon i am afraid that it is a problem with establishing connection with database.

Comment: @Devon how it it that i  check that db connection details are available? For example echo db connection details?